# How does the google reCAPTCHA data-callback event work

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha, captcha

This may be a stupid question so I'm sorry I'm new to web development. I am trying to write a page so it disables the search button until the reCAPTCHA is clicked (I know this can be circumvented by a spammer so this is not my concern). The way I have it currently set up is like this:

```
<div id="search_area">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function enableButton() {
            document.getElementById('search_submit').disabled = false;
        }
    </script>
    <input id="ch_search" size="50" type="text"/><button class="search_button" id="ch_search_submit" disabled="true">Search</button>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXX" data-callback = "enableButton()" ></div>
</div>
```

Currently just for initial testing I don't have a php validation checking form. When I check the text box and it turns green it is not enabling the search button as I would have thought it would. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this isn't working? Thank you for any help sorry about being a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I realized my problem was I was calling enableButton() and for it to work it needed to be enableButton without the parentheses.